# rails and metronic - assets precompile: SassC error, not enough space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4, metronic

I have developed a rails app, based on bootstrap. Now I'm using Metronic to improve the stylings but while I don't have any problem in development mode, trying to compile assets in production mode, I get this error:

> rake aborted! 
>   SassC::SyntaxError: Internal Error: Not enough space
>   /home/spanogi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/bundle:23:in 'load'
>   /home/spanogi/.rbenv/versions/2.4.3/bin/bundle:23:in '' 
>   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

the command I issue is

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

If I do not add Metronic assets to my application.scss and application.js precompilation regularly finishes.

The server resources seems to be abundant, I checked memory while compiling but it doesn't go over 30% of usage and in fact the error is generated internally by Sassc, not by the OS (it's not a memory crash). I looked for similar errors around but did not have any success.

Do you have ideas? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get it work.
I discovered that in SassC package "Not enough space" means "No UTF-8 encoded file"... (at least in my case) so all I had to do has been to convert the file to UTF-8 coding. I used this command (LINUX):

iconv -f UTF-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT filename -o output_file_name

then I had to clean the file from some "\0"s and everything worked.

Hope this could be useful to someone!

Answer (score 1):

I just remove `\0` from the css file and worked well